# Tracking variable changes in one object between X amount of objects

Tags: c++

I can show exact code (unfortunately), but here is the thing I'm trying to achieve, and I just don't know where to start with it.

I have X amount of objects, to make things easier I will assume there are two of them Obj5s and Obj10s.
There is also object Target.

Target have single property Health = 100 and Array that store Obj type Objects. But the last one is not important (I think).

Now both Obj5s and Obj10s reduce Target Health (but there can be arbitrary amount of objects affecting Target Health at the same time).

Obj5s reduce by 20 for 5 seconds.
Obj10s reduce by 10 for 10 seconds.

Now both objects are appiled to the target at the same time, so Target health should be:
100 - 20 - 10 = 70 
It should last for 5s.

After 5 seconds, Health is updated. Obj5s is removed and it's back to 100. Obj10s receive this information and it looks like this:
100 - 10 = 90;
For another 5 seconds.
After which it will be back to 100.

Classes is pesudocode

```
class Target
{

    float Health;
    Array<Obj*> AffectingObjs; 
}

class Obj
{
    float Damage;
    float Duration;
}

class Obj5s : Obj /it sets values
{
    Damage = 20;
    Duration = 5;
}
```

Code is actually running in game loop.

Now my question is, how do I make both Obj5s and Obj10s and any other ObjX aware of Health changes ?

Should Health value be pushed each time it change to Obj and they should update accordingly ? Or should both objs query the value constantly to check if it changed ?

I had the early implementation of the last approach but it didn't really worked the way I expected. Because after each query the value was also updated so I got the behaviour like:
100 - 10 = 90;
90 - 10 = 80;
80 - 10 = 70;
etc.
The point is that value should be set once on each Obj and changed only when other Obj modify it.

Any pointing in right direction on where to start looking for proper solution would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't provided any code I guess I'll answer your question with pseudo-code.

1. Make Health accessible via getter/setter functions.
2. Whenever setHealth(newVal) is called call something on all the AffectingObjs to tell them that the Target's health has been modified. If you don't want to call the object that's causing the immediate change then pass the object making the change in to setHealth and have setHealth only call those objects in AffectingObjs that are not the object passed in.

P.S. I'm not sure why you want your affecting objects to be notified of changes based on your description. It would seem that they should just deduct health when they start affecting the health and add back the health when they're done.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed it work that way now, but it is not accurate enough. If two of them are applied at the same time but have different duration, the one that will last longer will use information that is no longer true (Health is no longer modified by -20 from it's original value, because object that did that, no longer exists), but second object is not aware of that and still use value it acquired while being created.

Comment: And thanks for giving a tip. It's bit patch work right now but I got it working for now.